# Installshield LE: Require Office 2007 or greater doesn't work

Tags: c#, ms-office, installshield, installshield-le

I have a C# project that requires office 2007 or greater.

In my Installshield project I have checked the Office 2007 box in the requirements section, which seems to be exactly what I need, but when I run the resulting installer it does not detect my currently installed version of Office (2013).

I get a messagebox that says "Office 2007 or greater must be installed for this installation to continue."

Am I doing something wrong, or is Installshield incapable of doing what I need it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my own experience goes, it's just a POS. Sorry. Google around for yourself. I ran into huge issues because I was trying to detect 64-bit Office, and the LE version just wouldn't. My choices were to a) only ship to 32-bit users (lol) b) pay MORE money for the full version and pray that it worked (it probably wouldn't have) or c) roll my own installer. I'll let you figure out which one would be least painful for yourself.

Comment: You've confirmed my suspicions. I was crossing my figures hoping that someone had a miracle fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Installshield might just be looking in the wrong place. Also, if you installed your new office over an old office, it might be referring to the old office. Try reinstalling, and reply to this answer to tell me how it goes, whether it worked or not, etc.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Even if this does solve the problem, it is not a viable solution because I cannot force every user to reinstall Office so that they can install my application.

Comment: Yes, but however you distribute the application, you can most likely put a disclaimer on it, and/or link this or another thread with instructions on how to fix the problem you are experincing, because most people most likely wont have this problem

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. I've tried installation on a second pc with Office 2010 installed with the same result.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work. I'll do some digging on the matter, and if I find anything, I'll add another answer. Sorry about the wrong answer.